# 240v 4-wire power issue

Tags: electrical, 240v

To start, i repair hot tubs for a living and am not a licensed electrician. But I recently am having a problem with a job that I know I have had many years ago but I just can't remember what solution I came to back then.

Basically what's happening is I have a swim spa that is run off of 240V 4-wire system. Some of the components run off the circuit board are not working, so I tested the power at the circuit. I get 120V between both Hots and neutral. I also get 120V between both hots and ground.  But when I test both hots together, I do not get 240V as I should! Instead I get around 40 volts. I also tested this with the circuit board completely disconnected from the power so that it was not under a load, and I got all of the same readings except when I tested between the two hots, rather then get 240V I got .44V.

(editor's note: Google Voice Keyboard does not insert decimal points easily, so I am treating it as *bona-fide*.)

The strange part is that I went to the 50A sub-panel that feeds the circuit board, and I tested 240V going into and out from a 50 amp breaker. As far as I can tell there is nothing else between the sub panel in the circuit board.

This job is really out of the way and hard for me to schedule in this time of year.  I did have them call an electrician, but it seems that the electrician only looked at another part of the system that is completely unrelated, and they are having trouble getting him back out there or finding someone else to look at the system. So I thought I would ask for your guy's help as I know I ran into this issue many years ago and I just can't remember what the solution was.

We also called an electrician that works with us a little bit, but no useful information out of him; other than the 50A  breaker in the sub panel could be bad, which didn't make a lot of sense to me since we are getting good power coming out of it. Unfortunately when I was there I never checked neutral to ground. If anyone out there can refresh my memory or offer any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it, as they are really trying to get this resolved as soon as possible for 4th of July.

**UPDATE**

I appreciate you guys taking the time to get back to me and I apologize as I was clearly using speech to text crappy technology but I am multitasking as much as possible as we are in the final crunch for the 4th of July right now. After I submitted this question I think I found my own answer but just to reply to some things that were asked here...

These were my readings going into the TB1 at the circuit board:

@ board (while connected)
White-black 122v
White-red 116v
Green-black 120v (not exactly,  but within acceptable range)
Green-red 120v (not exactly,  but within acceptable range)
Black-red 44v

@ board (disconnected)

White-black 122v
White-red 116v
Green-black 120v (not exactly,  but within acceptable range)
Green-red 120v (not exactly,  but within acceptable range)lack-red Black-red.25v ( in my original post I wrote .44 but I was misremembering)

@ sub panel
Black-red IN 244
Black-red OUT 244

Yes the breaker in the sub panel is the one that feeds this system and no it is not to single pole Breakers but one double pole breaker, but what I found out by reading through a tech manual for this system is that the power does come out of that sub panel and go somewhere else before going over to the circuit board where I was having the problem. I had thought that both of these systems were independent of each other and I think that is where the problem was. This is an endless pool swim spa which has both a hydraulic swim jet system and also an electric heat system. Because I've never worked on one of these before I had assumed that they were independent of each other because that's how things looked at first glance. Most of the problem is just that we are overworked just do not have enough time to do everything we need so I didn't spend the time on and I would have liked to have spent. Still though I feel like I ran into this situation in my past and any other hot tubs that I've ever worked on would not have had something else between the sub panel and the hot tub. My assumption at this point is that I am also wrong about that and misremembering something I worked on in the past based on what you guys are saying.

If I am still wrong about where this is heading I will post back with my findings the next time I get out there but at this point it's nothing that I am going to fix anyways as I am not a licensed electrician and the problem seems to be and electrical whip between the main control box that is mounted to the hydraulic pump and the circuit board in the spa pack. Especially considering this endless pool since inside the house in their basement. Either way, like I said I appreciate your time and I'm sorry for all of the errors in my post. I will report back its problems on my end persist.

Comment: The second paragraph is hard to follow -- it reads as if auto-correct or speech-to-text put in a bunch of random words. Please proof-read and edit. It isn't clear where the meter leads were attached for the "around 40 volts" measurement, nor where they were attached for the "240 volts going into and out from a 50 amp breaker."

It sounds likely that the two hots are on the same half of the phase rather than being opposite as they should be. Edits to the question will help confirm.

Comment: @GregHill Numbers spelled out, random capitalizations, missing punctuation, obviously wrong but phonetically similar words... meet **Google Voice Keyboard**.

Comment: What wiring method was used for this run?

Comment: I agree with Greg Hill, this sounds like a classic case of someone using a pair of tandem breakers as a 2 pole breaker, which will not work if you want 240V because that tandem is only plugged into 1 bus bar. You must have 2 poles, each one off of a different bus bar to get 240V, otherwise you just have two x 120V circuits next to each other. You said that you tested it at "a" 50A breaker, but was that the correct 50A breaker that is feeding that circuit? I suspect not.